# SharePoint: How to set column width of the list widget on a page

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-list

I have seen this asked, but no solid answers yet.

In SharePoint online, I created a simple list with 3 columns.  One of the columns I would like to be 60% of the width.  I have tried to save the setting in the view, but when others look at it or I clear my cache, the width setting does not save.

Here is my process:

1. Create simple list, resize the 'long column' and save the view as "All Items".

[image]

2. Create a page and add the list widget.  Publish the page and it looks correct.

[image]

3. Clear my cache in the Browser:

[image]

4. Return to the page, and note that the spacing is back to default:

[image]

What am I missing.

Comment: Try the solution given here and let me know if it works for you: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/293683/sharepoint-modern-list-increase-column-width-with-json-issue/293686#293686

Comment: I tried that exact process and after clearing the Cache, it did not stay.

Answer (score 0):

The width of the column header can be resized by easy drag in modern list, and with JSON we can only set the width the content within the field to a fixed value like “500px” or a percentage value like “60%”. But unlike classic list, we cannot set the column header to a fixed size to all users.

Comment: Thanks but I am a bit confused by your response (probably just me).

I only care about the content width, so what would be the best method to set that width?

Also, switching to a classic list did not seem to let me adjust the width of the content either.